# How can i transfer a database in SQLyog?

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

I use SQLyog Ultimate ver11.11 on windows8.1. I need to transfer a database from another machine (which it uses SQLyog Ultimate ver11.11 too). What is easiest way for do it?(I mean how can i detach an already existing database in another machine and then attach it to mine?!)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps :

1) Export database from old system SQLyog. (You can find export option on right click of database)

2) Create database in second system with same name.

3) Import database to second system SQLyog.

Note : I would recomment to use mysql command line.

Just for your information.

For export : `mysqldump databaseName > databaseName.sql`

For import : `mysql databaseName < databaseName.sql`

**Note** : Make sure, you have created your database before importing, otherwise it will give you error with message database not found.

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to both databases then you can use SQL-Yogs copy database command, just right-click on the database to copy in the database list.